# eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch static web on local host

Tags: eclipse, macos, localhost

I am trying to run a static web page on my mac (Yosemite 10.10.2) using eclipse Luna.

When I run it for the first time it works perfectly fine. But as soon as I exit from eclipse, reopen it and click on run button then HTTP Preview progress gets stuck at 100% while showing:

> Preparing Launch delegate ... Launching delegate

The only workaround I've found so far is to exit eclipse, delete the whole workspace folder and run eclipse again. It works but it's so annoying. I tried this before with mountain lion OS and eclipse kepler and same thing happens.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Same issue, I added a port attribute for HTTP Preview Server and then it does not start

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after eclipse restart.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and it turns out that my mistake was changing /etc/hosts file configuration for 127.0.0.1. After removal of config changes, server worked.